# How to fit image inside the bootstrap card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to fit the images inside the card to width of the card, however the image is not stretched enough to fit in the card. So could you guys please show me the proper way to do this?

[image: Here is the image]

Thanks

Here is my HTML code for card

```css
.card {
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100% !important;
  /* takes the 100 % width of its container (.box div)*/
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToKWh.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Destiny 2</h5>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Developer: Bungie
      </li>
      <li>
        Genre: First-person shooter, MMOG
      </li>
      <li>
        Release Date: 2017
      </li>

    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">More</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Add to Favorites</a>
  </div>
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: the style you used is fine to make it stretch edge to edge, can you share screenshot with inspect element to which which is making conflict, you can selected .card and make screenshot

Comment: or add this on codepen or somewhere else to give you answer for your problem.

Comment: Your image has whitespace and border in it. It _does_ fit the card. What's your goal?

Comment: Also, Bootstrap 4.0.0 is very old. Use the latest version.

Comment: Voting to close because I'm not able to reproduce the problem.  The image automatically fits the with of the card when Bootstrap class "card-img-top" is applied. No customization is required.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use newest bootstrap version.
Your image have white border thats why this not fit. Edit your photo or use photo without white border